Create Session Driver Not Supported in PHP Version 7.4.1 and Laravel Version 5.8.38
I'm getting the below error when serving the project.
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Manager.php:99
Stack trace:
#0 ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Manager.php(71): Illuminate\Support\Manager->createDriver('file\r')
#1 ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider.php(47): Illuminate\Support\Manager->driver()
#2 ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(785): Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Session\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#3 ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(667): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure)) 
#4 ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(615): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('session.store', Array)
#5 ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Il in ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Manager.php on line 99
] not supported. in ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Manager.php:99
Stack trace:
#0 ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Manager.php(71): Illuminate\Support\Manager->createDriver('file\r')
#1..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider.php(47): Illuminate\Support\Manager->driver()
#2 ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(785): Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Session\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#3 ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(667): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure)) 
#4 ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(615): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('session.store', Array)
#5 ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Il in ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Manager.php on line 99

I tried clean composer install and removed cache.
I tried copying a vendor folder from a working local machine , but that dint worked

If you take a look at the error message here:
#0 ..\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Manager.php(71): Illuminate\Support\Manager->createDriver('file\r')

You will see that you're using an invalid session driver (look at the parameter being passed to the createDriver() method). If you open your .env file and look at your SESSION_DRIVER variable you should see that it has the value:
SESSION_DRIVER=file\r

Just remove the (\r) and change it to:
SESSION_DRIVER=file

And it should start working again

I don't have an /r in the env .
my env looks like this : SESSION_DRIVER='file'

Okay, so you have SESSION_DRIVER='file' on one line, right?
I mean it's not written on multiple lines
